# How to limit file system access to a specific folder when logged in through FTP?

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, ftp

I wonder how can I limit access to the file system when logged in through FTP. Currently, users will see all of the HDD. How can I limit `userA` to just `/www/userA` for example. I am using Ubuntu 11 with `vsftpd`

Answer (score 2):

If your users are local users or virtual users being treated as local users on the system then you can use the `chroot_local_user` directive in `vsftpd.conf`

```
chroot_local_user=yes
```

This will chroot all local users to the directory tree below their home directory.